# Node.js - csurf invalid csrf token

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, axios, csrf

I'm using the npm module csurf for generating a token. First I get the token from the server, which I then use for the /register request. When I'm reproducing the same steps with postman, it seems to work, but unfortunately not in the application. There it always throws the error message that the token is invalid

--- Server side ---

**csrfProtection.js**

```
import csrf from 'csurf';

export default csrf({
  cookie: true
});
```

**router.js**

```
import csrfProtection from './../../config/csrfProtection'
router.get('/csrfToken', csrfProtection, async (req, res, next) => {
  return res.send(req.csrfToken());
});

router.post(
  '/register',
  validationHelper({ validation: registerUserValidation }),
  csrfProtection,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    return res.send('user registered');
  }
);
```

**app.js**

```
const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors()
);
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

--- Client side ---

```
const token = await this.$axios.$get('/csrfToken')
// token has the value 1KFmMJVz-dspX9TJo8oRInPzgDA1VY28uqQw

    await this.$axios.$post(
      '/register',
      {
        name: 'test456',
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        password: '123456789'
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'csrf-token': token
        }   
      }
    )
```

Someone experienced the same problem? Frontend and backend are hosted on different domains.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recently fixed a similar issue regarding 403 for csrf token. A new CSRF token is generated for every post request that happens after the get csrf call.

I found that this is a CORS issue. I fixed by adding below code:

```
import cors from 'cors';
const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost'];
const corsoptions: cors.CorsOptions = {
  allowedHeaders: ["Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Cookie", "Content-Type", "Accept", "X-Access-Token", "Authorization"],
  credentials: true,
  methods: "GET,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    // allow requests with no origin 
    // (like mobile apps or curl requests)
    if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
      var msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not ' +
        'allow access from the specified Origin.';
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
  },
  preflightContinue: false,
};

export const handleCors = (router: Router) =>
  router.use(cors(corsoptions));
```

Please refer to cors package [https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors%22)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add it in your `app.js` below the `cookieParser` like so:

```js
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(csrfProtection)
```

You are successfully sending a CSRF token to the frontend in your `/csrfToken` but then your app is generating a new token in your `/post`.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#simple-express-example) to the respective documentation.