# Express invalid CSRF token error, I've tried suggestions from other questions to no avail

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm having issues with the invalid CSRF token error when trying to POST to my express backend. I tried looking for answers on here and Google but none of them seem to work. This is the code I have, shrunk down for simplicity:

```js
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const csurf = require("csurf");

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const user = await getUserInfo(token);

    res.json(user);
});

app.post(
    "/events/:id",
    express.json(),
    async (req, res) => {
        const data = await addEvent(req.params.id, req.body);
        res.json(data);
    }
);
```

I'm using axios to perform an AJAX request to the POST method, here is my axios object:

```js
const http = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    xsrfCookieName: "_csrf",
});
```

I can see in my Network tab on Chrome DevTools that a `_csrf` cookie is being saved on the browser, and a `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header is being sent, along with the cookie, with the request with the same value as the cookie. However, it's still giving me a 403 error.

Here are the options I've tried with `csurf`

```js
app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));
app.use(csurf({ cookie: true, value: (req) => req.headers["x-xsrf-token"] }));
app.use(csurf({ cookie: true, value: (req) => req.cookies["x-xsrf-token"] }));
```

I've also tried adding `res.cookies("_csrf", req.csrfToken())` to `app.get("/")`, and adding a middleware with `res.locals._csrf = req.csrfToken()` in it, but none of it have worked. Does anyone have any ideas to why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60915619/node-js-csurf-invalid-csrf-token

Comment: I'm proxying from axios to my backend so I don't have cors implemented, I don't think that applies to me.

Comment: did u fix this? plz